# Confused by Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

I'm a complete novice so sorry if this is a silly question.

I'm writing a Hubot script. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I need some help please. I'm trying to get scores from MLB.

I have this...

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.hear /score/i, (msg) ->
    url = 'http://mlb.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/year_2016/month_03/day_12/master_scoreboard.json'

    msg.send(getData(url))

  getData = (url) ->
    robot.http(url)
      .get() (err, res, body) ->
        result = JSON.parse(body)
        console.log(result.data.games.game[1].home_team_city)
        team = result.data.games.game[1].home_team_city
```

When I run the above the console.log statement prints "Boston" but the robot prints "[Object Object]" How do I get the robot to print "Boston." Note: I intend to re-use the getData function for a bunch of other responses.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: (1) Are you sure `.get() (err, res, body) ->` is right? Wouldn't you normally pass the callback to `get` rather than saying `get()(callback_function)` like you are? (2) CoffeeScript functions return the value of their last expression, that's probably where the `[Object Object]` comes from.

Comment: @muistooshort But the last statement is team, which is the same like console log. And from the hubot documentation, that syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The request doesn't return the result, because it's asynchronous. Meaning the result will only be available after the server responded.

It probably returns a Promise or something similar, or something to listen to the response.

Try this (I streamlines a bit as a coffeescript introduction, I hope it's still clear):

```
url = 'http://mlb.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/year_2016/month_03/day_12/master_scoreboard.json'

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.hear /score/i, getData

getData = (msg) ->
  robot
    .http url
    .get() (err, res, body) ->
      team = JSON.parse(body).data.games.game[1].home_team_city
      console.log team
      msg.send team
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use a callback... like so:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
robot.hear /score/i, (msg) ->
url = 'http://mlb.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/year_2016/month_03/day_12/master_scoreboard.json'
getData url, (cb) ->
  msg.send(cb)

getData = (url, successCallback) ->
robot.http(url)
  .get() (err, res, body) ->
    result = JSON.parse(body)
    console.log(result.data.games.game[1].home_team_city)
    team = result.data.games.game[1].home_team_city
    successCallback(team)
```